# Parent Activity of a Fragment is NULL upon Square Receipt Payment Signature

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent, square

I have a *MasterActivity* that has a few fragments. One fragment allows the user to open up Square to pay. *After* the user signs their name in Square and the data is returned to my app, my app crashes because the Payment fragment can't find the  *MasterActivity* as it is null.

**This only happens when the user signs the receipt**. If the user pays cash (no signature) the My App works fine.

I have noticed that the when the Square App is ready for a signature it rotates the screen, just before the signature capture activity is view-able, I can see my app rotate too.

After the Square application has returned to my app, I can see the successful upload of the data to my server from my app. Then, it is only when the payment fragment asks the *MasterActivity* to refresh the data, I get a `null pointer exception` for the **DISP_KEY** in *MasterAcitvity* .

**Can any see what I might be doing wrong?**

**MasterActivity**

```
public class MasterActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
    private String DISP_KEY = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_master);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        DISP_KEY = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("SELECTED_DISPATCH");

        initView();
        refreshData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }


    public void refreshData() {
     //Do some network download data stuff using the DISP_KEY

    }

    private void initView() {

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        //JUST TEXT
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Details"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Sections"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Area"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Notes"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Payments"));

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

**PaymentFragment**

```
public class PaymentFragment extends Fragment  {

    private static final int SQUARE_CHARGE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    private PosClient posClient;

    public PaymentFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor for fragments
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_payment, container, false);

        initGUI(view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mVehicle = ((MasterActivity) this.getActivity()).getCurrentVehicle();
        if (mVehicle != null) {
            reloadData();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        if (this != null) {
            ((MasterActivity) context).registerDataReloadListener(this);
            posClient = PosSdk.createClient(getActivity(), AppConfig.SQUARE_APP_ID);
        } else {
            ((MasterActivity) context).onBackPressed();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        if (this != null) {
            ((MasterActivity) getActivity()).unregisterDataReloadListener(this);
        }

    }

    public void reloadData() {
       //Ask the master activity to reload data
    }

     // SQUARE

    private void acceptSquarePayment() {
        ChargeRequest.TenderType types;
        ChargeRequest request = new ChargeRequest.Builder(Integer.parseInt(square_balance), CurrencyCode.USD)
                .enforceBusinessLocation(square_location_id)
                .restrictTendersTo(types)
                .requestMetadata(square_call_num)
                .autoReturn(3200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();

            Intent intent = posClient.createChargeIntent(request);
            startActivityForResult(intent, SQUARE_CHARGE_REQUEST_CODE);

    }

     // GET SQAURE RESULTS
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                ChargeRequest.Success success = posClient.parseChargeSuccess(data);
                sendReceiptToAPIServer(success.serverTransactionId, success.clientTransactionId, success.requestMetadata);
            } 

    }

    private void sendReceiptToAPIServer(String serverTransactionId, String clientTransactionId, String callNum) {
        //Do some data upload stuff

        //After the successufull upload, this is where the crash happens

        reloadData();
    }


     @Override
    public void onDataReload() {
        mVehicle = ((MasterActivity) this.getActivity()).getCurrentVehicle();

        if (getView() != null) {
            reloadData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure but try adding it to your activity entry in manifest  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

Comment: So what's the exception stack trace?